# Why is my ISession not flushed automatically when using Autofac?

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

### Overview

I'm trying to wire up Autofac to help manage NHibernate's `ISession` in my MVC 4 RC project. From what I understood, Autofac should call `ISession.Dispose` at the end of each HTTP request the way I configured it (see below). However, it doesn't seem to be the case - if I do not call `ISession.Flush()`, data is not persisted in the database.

### Configuration

#### Autofac

```
container.Register(c => DbConfig.Generate(connectionString).BuildSessionFactory())
    .As<ISessionFactory>()
    .SingleInstance();

container.Register(c => c.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
    .As<ISession>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    
container.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
    .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

#### Repository

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly ISession Session;
    
    public Repository(ISession session)
    {
        Session = session;
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        Session.Save(entity);
    }
}
```

#### Database seed (Application_Start)

```
public class DatabaseSeed
{
    public static void Seed(IContainer container)
    {
        var session = container.Resolve<ISession>();
        var userRepo = container.Resolve<IRepository<User>>();
        userRepo.Add(new User { Id = 5, Name = "Test User" });
        
        //session.Flush(); <-- if not called, user will not be persisted!
    }
}
```

### Closing remarks

I do know that I should be wrapping this in a transaction. However, I'd like to get the basics to work before moving on to more complex scenarios, and am puzzled as to why would the above not work the way I expected it to...

*(As a side note, I tried running Whitebox, the Autofac 'profiler', but it fails on me with some exception (posted on Autofac group @ Google), so I'm not entirely sure if it's Autfac that's making fun of me or NHibernate :-)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Committing the transaction will flush the session. Transactions are part of the basics.

*- Or -*

Turn on NHibernate logging and you'll see if AutoFac disposes the session and if NHibernate flushes itself.

You configured AutoFac that the session should be disposed at the end of the lifetimescope. Where did you configure that the lifetimescope should match a http request?

---

**UPDATE**

I just tested it myself and the session isn't being flushed if the session is disposed. Which makes sense, because the transaction you normally use will be committed before the session is disposed. Otherwise the session is flushed outside of a transaction.

So either set the flushmode to 'Always' or use transactions. Like I said in my original answer, transactions **are** part of the basics.

Comment: As I said, I know that wrapping the whole thing in a transaction and commiting it would solve the problem, but I'm trying to understand why a simpler solution does not seem to suffice. AFAIK `InstancePerLifetimeScope` defaults to instance per HTTP request when used in a web app.

Comment: That is why you could turn on the NHibernate logging to see what it does.

Comment: You are indeed correct in saying that `Dispose` does not, all by itself, cause all pending commands to execute. I was thinking it could be some Autofac-related, object-lifetime issue, but prompted by your testing I moved my db-init code to a controller and experienced the same behaviour. Not sure where I got the idea that `Dispose` should auto-flush unless told otherwise... From what others are saying on the interwebs, transactions are indeed expected to be used as standard part of any operation. Thanks for taking the time to respond and test!

Comment: This might help http://hammerproject.com/post/105830271149/flush-isession-at-the-end-of-request-lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about AutoFac, as my favourite DI framework is Spring.NET and its XMLs :).
But the problem with changes to object somehow did not persist is very familiar to me. In all cases that I got, they are related to the flush mode and transaction. I handle these with following procedure:

First to check is the transaction. Did it in place? It is strongly suggested that at least you do all updates/deletes in transaction. Let's assume that a transaction did started.

We come to the flush mode. What is the flush mode of the session? If it was Commit, changes should be persisted. If it was Auto, changes must also be persisted. So I think it was Never, which requires you to flush it manually using Session.Flush().

Comment: The trouble was that I was not using a transaction at all, just doing `ISession.Save(something)` and hoping that this would eventually be flushed / persisted when `ISession` is disposed. Now that I have transactions (still use `FlushMode.Auto`), the problem is gone and I can move on to more interesting things :-)